# Trimming specifc words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, data-cleaning, trim

I have a df with some trigrams (and some more ngrams) and I would like to check if the sentence starts or ends with a list of specific words and remove them from my df. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Trigrams+': ['because of tuna', 'to your family', 'pay to you', 'give you in','happy birthday to you'], 'Count': [10,9,8,7,5]})

list_remove = ['of','in','to', 'a']

print(df)

    Trigrams+            Count
0   because of tuna       10
1   to your family         9
2   pay to you             8
3   give you in            7
4   happy birthday to you  5
```

I tried using `strip` but in the example above the first row would return **because of tun**

The output should be like this:

```
list_remove = ['of','in','to', 'a']

    Trigrams+             Count
0   because of tuna        10
1   pay to you              8
2   happy birthday to you   5
```

Can someone help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
list_remove = ["of", "in", "to", "a"]

tmp = df["Trigrams+"].str.split()

df = df[~(tmp.str[0].isin(list_remove) | tmp.str[-1].isin(list_remove))]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Trigrams+  Count
0        because of tuna     10
2             pay to you      8
4  happy birthday to you      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x):
  y = x.split()[0]
  z = x.split()[-1]
  if (y in list_remove) or (z in list_remove):
     return np.nan
  return x

df['Trigrams+'] = df['Trigrams+'].apply(lambda x:func(x))
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```